# How to add custom search box in Django-admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I know this is gonna be a very basic question.

In Django, I have successfully created an admin panel. Now I want to add a custom search box in one of my field namely `Photo` field. But I don't know **how to add custom search box** in a django-admin panel. If I get some proper hints than I believe that I can do it.

**Admin.py**:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from photo.models import Photo


class PhotoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'approved', 'approved_time', 'uploaded_time', 'user')
```

**models.py:**

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos', blank=False, null=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    approved_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,null=True, blank=True)
    uploaded_time = models.DateTimeField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False , null=True)
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False, null=True)
    image_id = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    Certified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    approved_by = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    total_download = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    watermarked_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='temp', blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to add a custom search box in this `Photo` field where image can be searched by it's `ID`. Now how can I add this search box in my above given model.

Comment: On a side note, do not use `Certified` use `certified` instead for attribute name.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Use the [`search_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields) attribute of the `ModelAdmin`:

```
class PhotoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    search_fields = ['name', 'description', 'user__related_fieldname', 'keyword']
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. i want to search item by ID,should i include `id` or `photo.id` in `search_fields` parameter ?

Comment: Yes, add the `'id'` field to the `search_fields`.

Comment: and for those who come after, you could search on related model fields, too `search_fields = ('name', 'relatedfield__name')`

Answer (score 26):

cant reply due to low karma..

but don't forget to register the Admin Model too, like

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

admin.site.register(Photo, PhotoAdmin)
```

Comment: Got AttributeError: type object 'ModelAdmin' has no attribute '_meta'.

Comment: I fixed the code in the answer to avoid some headaches to SO copy-pasters. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Adding Dan Walters answer, you can also search if you don't know the exact word with `__icontains`

```
class PhotoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    search_fields = ['name__icontains', 'description', 'user__related_fieldname', 'keyword__icontains',
]
```

it's equivalent to `LIKE` in SQL

Answer (score 3):

When you write:

```
admin.site.register([Photo, PhotoAdmin])
```

you register in admin two models: Photo and PhotoAdmin, you must register Model and ModelAdmin for it, like this:

```
admin.site.register(Photo, PhotoAdmin)
```